# Standard Error of Variance Component from the output of GLMMadaptive::mixed_model

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, glmm, glmmadaptive

I am using the [`{GLMMadaptive}`](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/index.html) package to fit a mixed effect random slope model. And I need to extract the standard error of variance components from the output of  `GLMMadaptive::mixed_model()`. And [from the package documentation](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Methods.html), it seems that I can use the [`vcov()`](https://rdrr.io/r/stats/vcov.html) method to extract the variance of the random components. But I am confused by the returned values.

Consider the following reprex from the package article [Methods for MixMod Objects](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/articles/Methods.html)

```r
library(GLMMadaptive)

set.seed(1234)
n <- 100 # number of subjects
K <- 8 # number of measurements per subject
t_max <- 15 # maximum follow-up time

# we construct a data frame with the design: 
# everyone has a baseline measurement, and then measurements at random follow-up times
DF <- data.frame(id = rep(seq_len(n), each = K),
                 time = c(replicate(n, c(0, sort(runif(K - 1, 0, t_max))))),
                 sex = rep(gl(2, n/2, labels = c("male", "female")), each = K))

# design matrices for the fixed and random effects
X <- model.matrix(~ sex * time, data = DF)
Z <- model.matrix(~ time, data = DF)

betas <- c(-2.13, -0.25, 0.24, -0.05) # fixed effects coefficients
D11 <- 0.48 # variance of random intercepts
D22 <- 0.1 # variance of random slopes

# we simulate random effects
b <- cbind(rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D11)), rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D22)))
# linear predictor
eta_y <- as.vector(X %*% betas + rowSums(Z * b[DF$id, ]))
# we simulate binary longitudinal data
DF$y <- rbinom(n * K, 1, plogis(eta_y))

fm <- mixed_model(fixed = y ~ sex * time, random = ~ time | id, data = DF,
                  family = binomial())
```

Now the estimated variance-covariance matrix of the maximum likelihood estimates of random effects is returned using the [`vcov()`](https://rdrr.io/r/stats/vcov.html) method,

```r
vcov(fm, parm = "var-cov")

#>             D_11        D_12       D_22
#> D_11  0.42942062 -0.09963969  0.5065884
#> D_12 -0.09963969  0.03701847 -0.2117451
#> D_22  0.50658839 -0.21174511  1.3651870
```

Then that package article says about the returned value of `vcov`,

> The elements of this covariance matrix that correspond to the elements of the covariance matrix of the random effects (i.e., the elements D_xx) are on the log-Cholesky scale.

I am really confused by the above line. What does it mean by *The elements of this covariance matrix are on the log-Cholesky scale.*?

Please Note that my end goal is to get the standard errors of the estimated random effects that is, $Se(D_{11})$, $Se(D_{12})$, $Se(D_{22})$.  **So do I need to apply any transformation on the resulting matrix to get these? If so, how?**

---

*Note that: I am aware of [this Q/A thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31694812/10858321) from stackoverflow that contains very useful discussion about this, but that uses `{lme4}` package. But my issue is specifically about the `{GLMMadaptive}` package.*

Comment: Please Note that, this question [is cross posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76893203/10858321), but found no help so far :(

Comment: @DimitrisRizopoulos might have some useful input beyond my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [delta method](https://www.statlect.com/asymptotic-theory/delta-method) to calculate standard errors (of the estimators of the entries of the random effects' covariance matrix) on the variance-covariance scale.

Note, however, that there are better alternatives to quantify uncertainty (e.g., in terms of differently constructed confidence intervals) of such estimators.

In the code below, the function `D_chol_to_D` (corresponding to $g$ in the linked StatLect article) is the transformation from the log-Cholesky parameterization of the entries of the random effects' covariance matrix to the original variances and covariances. The function `numDeriv::jacobian` computes a numerical approximation to the value of the Jacobian matrix of $g$ (denoted by $J_g$ in the StatLect article) at the MLE `D_chol_entries` of the log-Cholesky parameterized random effects' covariance matrix.

```r
library("numDeriv")

# estimated covariance matrix of random effects
D <- fm$D

# transform from covariance matrix to entries of cholesky factor with 
# log-transformed main diagonal
D_chol_entries <- GLMMadaptive:::chol_transf(D)

D_chol_to_D <- function(x) {
  
  # transform from entries of cholesky factor with log-transformed main diagonal
  # to covariance matrix
  D <- GLMMadaptive:::chol_transf(x)
  
  D[upper.tri(D, diag = TRUE)]
}

J <- jacobian(D_chol_to_D, D_chol_entries)

# estimated covariance matrix of D_chol_entries
V_chol <- vcov(fm, parm = "var-cov")

# estimated covariance matrix of entries of D
V <- J %*% V_chol %*% t(J)

se <- sqrt(diag(V))

cat("--- D_11 ---\nEstimate:", D[1, 1], "\nStd. Error:", se[1], fill = TRUE)
# --- D_11 ---
# Estimate: 0.4639974 
# Std. Error: 0.5992368
cat("--- D_22 ---\nEstimate:", D[2, 2], "\nStd. Error:", se[3], fill = TRUE)
# --- D_22 ---
# Estimate: 0.06304059 
# Std. Error: 0.02843676
```

Comment: Would you kindly explain how `D_chol_to_D()` is working here along with  `numDeriv::jacobian()`?

Comment: @shafee Edited, hope it helps understanding the code better.

Comment: You are saying "the function `D_chol_to_D` is the transformation from the log-Cholesky parameterization to the original", but from the source code of [`chol_transf`](https://github.com/drizopoulos/GLMMadaptive/blob/master/R/Functions.R#L140C1-L158C2), I think it is doing the opposite. (Sorry if I am wrong and please bear with me and I highly appreciate your help)

Comment: Oh I think I get it. It's the [`else block of chol_transf()`](https://github.com/drizopoulos/GLMMadaptive/blob/master/R/Functions.R#L148C7-L157C6X) that is actually executed inside the function `D_chol_to_D`. 
And $se[2] = SE(D_{12})$ and $se[3] = SE(D_{22})$, Right?

Comment: @shafee That's exactly right.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciate your help. However I posted [the same question on SO too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76893203/10858321) with bounty. If you want you can answet the same there too. Thanks again.

Comment: @shafee You're welcome. I've copied my answer to SO.